# Ordenação de Coluna de Tabela Secundária

Tags: mysql

```
Categoria       Segmento

1               Atendimento
1               Tempo de espera pela peça
1               Preço

2               Atendimento
2               Negociação
2               Tempo de entrega do veículo

3               Atendimento
3               Preço
3               Serviço
```

Eu tenho uma tabela onde salvo alguns dados nessa ordem acima. Se for a categoria 1, salvo aqueles segmentos naquela ordem.

Eu estou mostrando esses dados em outra página, porém os dados não estão vindo na mesma ordem em que é salvo na tabela. Segue o `SELECT`.

```
select 
    segmento, 
    categoria, 
    round(avg(dealer_rating_categories.rating)) as media 
from 
    `dealer_ratings` 
inner join 
    `dealer_rating_categories` on `dealer_rating_categories`.`id_avaliacao` = `dealer_ratings`.`id` 
inner join 
    `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `dealer_rating_categories`.`id_categoria` 
where 
    `dealer_ratings`.`deleted_at` is null 
and 
    `dealer_ratings`.`id_concessionaria` = 1 
and 
    `dealer_ratings`.`id_concessionaria` is not null 
and 
    `dealer_rating_categories`.`id_categoria` in (1, 2, 3) 
group by 
    `dealer_rating_categories`.`id_categoria`, `segmento` 
order by 
    `categories`.`ordem`
```

> Resultado

```
Categoria               Segmento

Compra de Veículo       Atendimento
Compra de Veículo       Negociação
Compra de Veículo       Tempo de entrega do veículo

Serviço                 Preço
Serviço                 Serviço
Serviço                 Atendimento

Peças                   Preço
Peças                   Atendimento
Peças                   Tempo de espera pela peça
```

O único que está correto é a categoria de Compra de Veículo que é o ID 2. Os outros, o segmento vem fora de ordem.

Apenas detalhando:

Eu não tenho os segmentos cadastrados separadamente em outra tabela ligando com a tabela categoria. Eu insiro manualmente no código. Caso contrário, eu criaria uma coluna `ORDEM` nessa tabela e acrescentaria um `ORDER BY ORDEM` no `SELECT` e resolveria o problema.

Mas como não é esse o caso, o que posso fazer ?

Comment: Você pode reduzir a performance do servidor e mandar ordenar pela string/varchar. Digo, `ORDER BY "categories"."ordem", segmento `

Comment: Vou testar, mas não posso ordenar por segmento porquê não estão em ordem alfabética. Está em ordem de inserção.

Comment: Acabei de testar e já está dessa forma, pois estou usando o Laravel.

Comment: Isso não faz sentido... mesmo que má prática ordenar por texto, deveria funcionar esse order by em 2 campos, na forma que coloquei claro: primeiro pelo ID/Ordem, depois pelo texto

Comment: Sim, funciona. Mas quando ordena pelo primeiro campo, mistura o segundo ao invés de mostrar pela ordem de inserção, como está em primeiro na minha pergunta.

Comment: Ah certo, eu me enganei, perdão. Agora entendi, você quer retornar na mesma ordem histórica que foram inseridos. Por causa de como a paginação e a indexação de busca funciona, acho que nunca vai retornar da mesma ordem que você inseriu, digo, não 100%. Sem um campo auxiliar não existe um boa solução pra isso... Talvez fazer um select por cada ID resolva... não tenho certeza.